How can I scale an instance based on the size of another objects face in geometry nodes?
I'm trying to scale instances that are centered on the side faces of a cylinder so I can build a procedural column generator. I want to be able to scale the instances to the XYZ of the faces on the side of the cylinder so that when I scale the cylinder, or add or subtract faces, it will scale to fit within the boundaries of the face.
I've tried multiple things based on separating the XYZ, trying to use math nodes and float curves, and then rejoining the XYZ so I can plug it into the scale. None of which I have attempted have worked, either it scales larger and larger the more faces I add and shrink as I take them away, or it doesn't even show up.

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Objective

To instance a smaller cylinder centred on each lateral face of a bigger cylinder, all cylinders being aligned.
To constrain the radius of the smaller cylinder to be a fraction of the width of the lateral faces of the bigger one.


Left: The bigger cylinder is made of 4 faces, and the scale of the smaller one is 99% of a lateral face.
Centre: The bigger cylinder is made of 8 faces, and the scale of the smaller one is 50% of a lateral face.
Right: The bigger cylinder is made of 16 faces, and the scale of the smaller one is 10% of a lateral face.
Geometry Nodes modifier

1. The supporting object is firstly generated with a Cylinder node whom Fill Type is set to N-Gon.
2. A Separate Geometry node is used to recover the polygon at the top, which is made only of edges as long as the lateral faces width.
3. A Sample Index node set in Edge domain is triggering the computation of the edges length, based on an Edge Vertices node to get the end points position, followed by a Distance vector math node. Because this length is the same for all edges, the Index value to sample is irrelevant. So it is hardcoded as 0.
4. The largest radius is computed as half this length using a Multiply math node.  This value is then multiplied by the user-defined Input parameter "Scale".
5. A cylinder as long as the supporting one is created with the computed Radius using an other Cylinder node.
6. A Mesh to Points node whom Selection mask is connected to the Side output socket of the first Cylinder node is defining where the second cylinder is duplicated by an Instance on Points node.
Resources: 

Thank you for fixing my problem, I just had one more quick question if possible, would this work for scaling the depth on the Z axis as well? should I find the specific index for the sample geometry node?

Assuming that you are not creating both Cylinders in the same GN modifier, for the Depth, I would rather use a BoundingBox node, then compute the difference between Z Max and Z min after a Separate XYZ node. In the same GN modifier, just use a Value constant node and plug it in both Cylinder nodes.
